# Can I use CloudWatch Event to trigger Lambda function that has variety event value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a question to use CloudWatch Event.

We will support a mailing service daily for various customers using AWS Lambda and CloudWatch Event.

Fortunately, we don't need a variety of function codes, just need one function code to execute the mailing program.

But we need a variety of Lambda test event values. For example customer's email address, kind of resources.

I think we don't need to duplicate the Lambda function for each customer if we can alternately input values into the test event.

But I don't know how to make a CloudWatch Event that triggers the Lambda input test event value to run by changing it.

Can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention what type of trigger is being used, so I will assume that it is a **scheduled event**.

When configuring the **Target** for the event as an AWS Lambda function, you can "Configure input". This will control what information is sent to the function in the `event` record.

For your use-case, you could use **Constant (JSON text)** to pass a static set of parameters to the function. This information would come through in the `event` record, which your Lambda function can parse and then act appropriately.

[image: Event target input configuration]

Please note that these are *not* 'test events' -- they are the *real* events that are sent through to the function. 'Test' events are only used in the AWS Lambda management console when you use the **Test** button, to simulate a normal triggering of the function.